# PHP 5.4.11 / Apache 2.4.2 on Windows 7 Pro . php files only run in DocumentRoot

Tags: php

I'm just starting up with stuff, so bear with me pls. Decided to teach myself WAMP. Installed and running Apache 2.4.2 ok. Installed PHP 5.4.11 ok.  In Apaches  httpd.conf I changed my documentroot path from the Apache default to "C:\Web"  In that folder resides a folder called testsite .. Here's the problem: I then created a file called info.php to test php running ok

- `http://localhost/index.html`            runs ok
- `http://localhost/testsite/index.htm`l   runs ok
- `http://localhost/info.php`              runs ok
- `http://localhost/testsite/info.php`     DOESNT RUN

Any help as to why the same php file doesnt run in my subfolder would be appr.

Comment: Check the file permissions for your subdirectory. That's the most common reason.

Comment: You need to verify that you changed both "DocumentRoot" and the corresponding "<Directory ...>" entries in httpd.conf. You also need to verify that you're not overriding the handlers in a .htaccess. As @AmalMurali mentions, you should also check your file/directory permissions.